# XML Variable as Razor MVC operator for OG Tags?

Tags: xml, xslt, razor, razor-pages, facebook-opengraph

I'm pretty new to Razor MVC and am working with some software that doesn't provide modern functionality. Therefore, I'm trying to dynamically build OG Tags using calls like "@Model.MetaTitle" in some of my HTML based C sharp partials (.cshtml).

This is for a e-commerce site.

So far, I've come up with a lot of ways to produce most of the Open Graph tags dynamically, here's my code:

```
<title>@Model.MetaTitle</title>
<meta name="description" content="@Model.MetaDescription" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com@(Request.RawUrl.Split(new[] {'?'})[0])" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="@Model.MetaTitle" />
<meta property="og:description" content="@Model.MetaDescription" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com@(Request.RawUrl.Split(new[] {'?'})[0])" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="@Model.MetaTitle" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="@Model.MetaDescription" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My Website" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@("@my_twitter")" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@("@my_twitter")" />
```

As you can see, the only data left to be filled here is the "og:image" propertie(s).

The page views are generated using XSLT/XML and in some cases, I can grab certain data using the Razor syntax. Even though the "ProductImage" is being called in on every XSLT/XML file, its declared as a variable like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$ProductImage" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

So how to pass this "$ProductImage" which outputs the url to the store product into my meta "og:image" property with limited access to the build?

I have come up with a way using jQuery but, the Facebook Object Debugger is still complaining about missing og:image tag. Assuming the scripted tags aren't being passed in time.

Example (pulling from existing schema.org data on page):

```
var ogUrl = $(".product-page meta[itemprop='image']").attr("content");

$('head').append("<meta property='og:image' content='" + ogUrl + "'/>");
$('head').append("<meta property='og:image:secure_url' content='" + ogUrl + "'/>");
$('head').append("<meta name='twitter:image' content='" + ogUrl + "' />");
```

This is where I'm currently stuck. Need to pass the url to the product image in the og tags... TIA.

**Update** this is the string where the variable is formed:

```
 <xsl:variable name="ProductImage" select="aspdnsf:LookupProductImage(ProductID, ImageFilenameOverride, SKU, 'large', 1, $AltText)"/>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Razor, but your `$ProductImage` is not declared anywhere in your sample code.  The `<xsl:value-of select="$ProductImage" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` line does not declare any variable -- it's simply a statement that, wherever this `xsl:value-of` statement is located, the code will output the value of the `$ProductImage` variable.  To find the declaration, look for something like `<xsl:variable name="ProductImage" ...>`.

Comment: Thanks Eirikr, I have found the declaration: <xsl:variable name="ProductImage" select="aspdnsf:LookupProductImage(ProductID, ImageFilenameOverride, SKU, 'large', 1, $AltText)"/> still not sure how to populate this in the meta tags.

Answer (score -1):

If you have XSLT view engine, then you can use the variable to create required meta tags by using `ProductImage` variable.
I am assuming that is not the case (or you are not allowed to).

If you are using xslt to generate razor views, then the answer to pass the variables will depend on the implementation of engine.

Easiest solution in my opinion would be to directly use

> LookupProductImage(ProductID, ImageFilenameOverride, SKU, "large", 1,
>   "")

in the viewmodel (by passing other appropriate variables) as it is definitely a C# function in your project. Then you can simply use the product image url by accessing it like other variables i.e., `@Model.variable` fashion.

Comment: Thanks RKalra, I'm still a bit confused but going to try some things. For example, the "other appropriate vars" would help a lot. Where would I declare this new var? The header info is in a .cshtml file and the XSLT is coming from a ".config" file (which I believe to be XML).

Comment: The model is obviously a class in your project. An instance of it is passed to razor view engine which makes it available in your view. The appropriate variables for LookupProductImage function are ProductID, ImageFilenameOverride and SKU. If they are not found in the model's class itself, you should check their initialization in xslt to see what can be done in the C# code.

Comment: Maybe you missed the parts in my op where I stated that I'm new to this and have limited access. Some code examples would be nice. Maybe someone else can help unfortunately the bounty has expired and I can't award it based on what's here.